# image byte stream manipulation

Tags: android

I have 1Kb of the bytes from an Image,can I make that part of Image b/w in any way(Reference:I want to manipulate large Images in android,so I am trying to make that b/w by using a Byte Stream)
Thank you in advance for your valuable time...

Answer (score 1):

It is not a solution, just idea.
Convert that stream to color array. You can decode Bitmap through BitmapFactory.decodeStream method. Then call bitmap.getPixels method to get int array with color values. And after that you can change color of any pixel of the bitmap.

Comment: The image might not be a bitmap(as android camera supports images in many formats like PNG,JPEG etc),how about those cases?

Comment: It could be converted to bitmap. If you don't want to convert it my idea doesn't fit.

Comment: I can't convert because,If I wanted to convert then I will have to load the image into memory,which will cause application to crash.